# I need to convert the logged-in webpage to PDF. How can I pass the cookie obtained by selenium get_cookies () to pdfkit?

Tags: python, pdfkit

code show as below:

```
    option = {'cookie': [(d['name'], d['value']) for d in driver.get_cookies()]}
    pdfkit.from_url(driver.current_url, 'test.pdf',options=option)
```

```
The output PDF file is blank.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,[in `pdfkit` official document](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/),it need a list full of tuple.

In your code,you used `dict5.items()`,it isn't a list.
You could use

```
ops = {'cookie':list(cookie_list)}
```

---

But your code could be reduce to:

```
option = {'cookie':[(d['name'],d['value']) for d in driver.get_cookies()]}
pdfkit.from_url(driver.current_url, 'test.pdf',options=option)
```

Comment: thank.
After converting dict to list, the program does not report an error, but the converted file is blank.
Cookies seem to have no effect.

In the previous code, I first obtained the selenium cookie, then extracted the name and value fields to generate a list.

Comment: thank.
After converting dict to list, the program does not report an error, but the converted file is blank.
Cookies seem to have no effect.

In the previous code, I first obtained the selenium cookie, then extracted the name and value fields to generate a list.

Comment: @Turalyon Each key-value pair should be (key,value).Have you tried my idea?maybe you could use `print(ops)` or `print(option)` to see the result.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMAI printed the results of ops and compared the cookies printed by selenium. The content is the cookie name and value extracted from selenium.

Comment: I tried your code, the result is the same, all are blank.

Comment: @Turalyon Maybe you also need other request headers.Add them in the `options`,